# How to draw rectangle like the screen shot selection on OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift

[image]

How does the rectangle redraw? Is this on a NSWindow? or NSScreen? How can I do that on OS X native's APIs? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357960/drawing-selection-box-rubberbanding-marching-ants-in-cocoa-objectivec

Comment: You would create a transparent overlay window over the screen and draw the outline and semi-transparent rectangle on that window.

Comment: i was about to comment same, @KenThomases. After that you need to subclass view and windows and drawRect...bezier path etc

Comment: So, is this mean that the NSWindows need to keep resizing?

Comment: You do not have to subclass NSWindow, if the area of the selection is insider your app's window. It is only needed, if you want to draw such a rect outside your own windows.